# MySQL Returning 1 or 0 based on ID found

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, where-clause

Here is a snippet of the tables in question:

**USER**

```
|  USER_UID  |  FIRSTNAME  |  LASTNAME  | 
    abc123         bob          smith
    def456         rob          smithies 
    ghi789         john         clark
```

**EVENT**

```
| GUID | NAME |  
  ev1   event1
  ev2   event2
  ev3   event3
```

**USER_EVENT**

```
| USER_EVENT_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
       1            abc123     ev1
       2            def456     ev2
       3            ghi789     ev3
```

**EVENT_VOTE**

```
| EVENT_VOTE_ID | USER_UID | EVENT_UID | 
         1         def456      ev1       (user2 voted for user1's event)
```

I have the following query which returns the event with the number of votes and a rank based on this:

```
SELECT t.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM ( SELECT e.guid,
              e.name,
              ( SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
                FROM event_vote ev 
                WHERE ev.event_uid = e.guid
              ) AS votes
              FROM event e
      ) AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

---

I also want to return either 1 or 0 if a user is ineligible to vote or not.

A user is ineligible to vote if:

- the user is the owner of the event.
- the user has already voted for that event (users uid and event uid are found in event_vote).

The following code after **...AS votes** gave me the correct response if a user had already voted but not if they owned the event.

```
,(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM event_vote ev
    WHERE ev.event_uid = e.guid
    AND ev.user_uid = '{$user_uid}'
 ) AS ineligible
```

**Expected Result (from user 2s perspective when viewing all events)**

```
guid: ev1
name: event1
votes: 1 
rank: 1
ineligible: 1 (already voted).

guid: ev2
name: event2
votes: 0
rank: 2
ineligible: 1 (user owns this event)

guid: ev3
name: event3
votes: 0 
rank: 3
ineligible: 0 (user doesn't own this event and has yet to vote).
```

Comment: `the user has already voted for that event` ... can you point out where this happens in your data?

Comment: in the event_vote table, sorry i'll update it now, typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query with a `case when` expression giving a 1 or `null`. This is aggregated as a `count(distinct ...)` which gives 1 only when there is at least one 1 in the aggregated values, and 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT      t.*,
            @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM        (
                SELECT     u.user_uid,
                           e.guid, 
                           e.name, 
                           count(ev.user_uid) votes, 
                           count(distinct 
                               case when u.user_uid in (ev.user_uid, ue.user_uid)
                                    then 1 
                               end) ineligible 
                FROM       user u
                CROSS JOIN event e
                INNER JOIN user_event ue
                        ON ue.event_uid = e.guid
                LEFT JOIN  event_vote ev
                        ON ev.event_uid = e.guid
                GROUP BY   u.user_uid, 
                           e.guid
                ORDER BY   votes desc,
                           e.guid,
                           u.user_uid
            ) as t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE      t.user_uid = 'def456'
ORDER BY   votes desc,
           guid, 
           user_uid
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/TTKD33109).

Be aware that when you use variables like that, you must force the order in the *inner* query. If you only do it on the outer query, it really comes too late as then the variable expressions have already been evaluated. It might work often though, as the optimiser may take into account the outer `order by`, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to check if the User_UID is exists for the voted on event in the User_Event table. If it does, the voter, is the owner.

something like: (PSEUDO I am not near a compiler)

```
     IF EXISTS (Begin
        select User_Event_Id 
        from User_event 
        where User_UId = @user_uid 
        (@user_uid the user trying to vote) 
        and where Event_Id = @Event 
        (@Event = event of the id, the user is trying to vote for)
        End)
        Begin
        if(--Check if user has voted for event (code you already wrote)
        --User is eligible
        else
        --User not eligible
        End

    ELSE
        --User not eligible
```

But, it might better to simply spend the time to merge these two requests without result to if statements.